# How to select maximum no. of similar records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in *Oracle*

`Flight` :

```
-------------------------
fl_no | fl_date | fl_time
-------------------------
```

`Passenger` :

```
------------------------------------
ps_id | fl_no | ps_name | ps_address
------------------------------------
```

Now I need to show the flight that has most passenger. But I'm just not able to figure out the query. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does your query look like so far? How should its result be different?

Comment: Please expand on your reading of "similar records from a table" in the title of your request (or re-phrase, if appropriate).

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than one flight has the same, maximum, number of passengers? Show both, pick one at random, or pick one based on some secondary criteria?

Comment: show both the flights

Answer (score 3):

You can use analytic functions (`dense_rank`) to reduce the query to one table scan: (to improve the speed at which the query runs)

```
select *
  from (select fl_no,
               num_pass,
               dense_rank() over(order by num_pass desc) as rnk
          from (select fl_no, count(*) as num_pass
                  from passenger
                 group by fl_no))
 where rnk = 1
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a1d1/10/0

(notice how in the fiddle I made a tie between flights 1 and 3; both have exactly 3 passengers, the highest # of passengers in any flight)

As noted already, join into the `flight` table if you need additional fields returned from that table. For instance if you wanted to add on the date of each such flight with the most passengers you could run:

```
select x.*, f.fl_date
  from (select fl_no,
               num_pass,
               dense_rank() over(order by num_pass desc) as rnk
          from (select fl_no, count(*) as num_pass
                  from passenger
                 group by fl_no)) x
  join flight f
    on x.fl_no = f.fl_no
 where rnk = 1
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/286bf/1/0

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with `order by` and `rownum`:

```
select *
from (select fl_no, count(*) as cnt
      from passenger p
      group by fl_no
      order by cnt desc
     ) f
where rownum = 1;
```

Although window functions can be used, they seem like overkill.

Note that in Oracle 12+, this can be simplified to:

```
select fl_no, count(*) as cnt
from passenger p
group by fl_no
order by cnt desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

EDIT:

If you want all such flights, then analytic functions are the way to go.  Here is another way to write such a query (Brian already has one method):

```
select *
from (select fl_no, count(*) as cnt, max(count(*)) over () as maxcnt
      from passenger p
      group by fl_no
      order by cnt desc
     ) f
where cnt = maxcnt;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what the OP wants. The want to show all flights that have the top count.